# Why are my SYNCHRONOUS JavaScript functions occurring in the wrong order?

Tags: javascript, canvas, synchronous

In every question I can find about functions being called in the wrong order, they're either talking about asynchronous functions or completely asynchronous languages. I know what to do with asynchronous functions, and I've never had this problem with synchronous functions before (and according to my Google and StackOverflow searches, neither has anyone else ). But when I call these functions in my draw loop:

```js
function draw() {
  c.clear();
  c.background('red');
  player.update();
}
```

My player is being drawn first. I know this because I tried adjusting where the clearing and background drawing was happening, and the player is being drawn just fine outside of those areas.
I'm also pretty sure it's happening before *either* of those functions because the same thing happens when I have only one (except, obviously, the canvas will be clear if I don't add the background).

I think it's probably something wrong with the functions I'm calling, so here they are:

```js
Canvas.prototype.background = function(color,origin=[0,0]) {
  this.ctx.fillStyle = color;
  this.ctx.fillRect(origin[0],origin[1],this.width,this.height);
}
Canvas.prototype.clear = function(origin=[0,0]) {
  this.ctx.clearRect(origin[0],origin[1],this.width,this.height);
}

update() { //this one's inside a class
  this.x += this.velX;
  this.y += this.velY;
  this.draw();
}
draw() { //this one too
  if (this.sprite) {
    this.canvas.sprite(this.sprite,this.x,this.y,this.drawOptions)
  }
}
Canvas.prototype.sprite = function(sprite,x,y,options={}) {
  this.ctx.beginPath();
  if (typeof HTMLElement === "object" ? sprite instanceof HTMLElement || sprite instanceof HTMLImageElement
  : sprite && typeof sprite === "object" && sprite !== null && sprite.nodeType === 1 && typeof sprite.nodeName==="string")
    this.ctx.drawImage(sprite,x,y);
  //then there's an else and whatever but the image I'm sending in is an HTMLImageElement so it does this one
}
```

Did I accidentally make some of these asynchronous or something? Why is the sprite being drawn before the canvas is cleared and/or filled?

Comment: Just add `console.log(my function name)`  in each function and it will tell you the sequence they are being executed in.

Comment: Can you please make a [mcve], showing how `c` and `player` are defined, and including your draw loop?